# How to center text in middle of text color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put text in the middle of a colored box. When I try to center the text, it centers it but the text is still toward the top of the box and not in the middle. How do I move it down so it's in the middle of the background color? Should I be using something else instead of background color?

```
h1 {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
background-color: #C28FE2;
text-align: center;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use Flexbox for your solution. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LwzqXB

Comment: You mean vertically middle inside box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I move it down so it's in the middle of the background color?

You can implement it with flexbox.

Try this:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color: #C28FE2;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  /*added code from here*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>This is heading</h1>
```

> Should I be using something else instead of background color?

No, `background-color` is correct property you are going for. The only thing is instead of applying `background-color` to `h1`, you can apply it to some `div` or `section` and insert `h1` inside it. This will save you from giving height to `h1`, which is less frequently observed as `100px` height.